# jQuery Dialog, hiding an element in the dialog upon close

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm using the jQuery UI Dialog function and upon close, I would like to hide one of the elements which was in my dialog.

I'm attempting to do this within the close event of the Dialog function but it's not working. I am guessing because that element no longer exists at the time of close.

Here's the code.

```
// Dialog settings for our edit dialog's
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    close: function(event, ui){
         $("#myDiv").hide();
    }   
});


<div id="myDialog">
   <div id="myDiv">This div should hide when the user closes the dialog, but it stays open when I re-open the dialog.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The div inside your dialog is not being hide with the dialog?

Comment: The div in my dialog shows by default, and when I close my dialog I want it to hide.

Comment: can you provide also your CSS?

Comment: There's no CSS. Just trying to access a div within a dialog and hide it upon close.

Comment: I believe it's because the dialog is a clone of the original html.  And your selector is only hiding the original div which is already hidden.

Comment: Let me be clear, the case I am accounting for is if the user first opens the dialog. Then opens it again, the second time they open it, it should be hidden because I hid it upon close.

Comment: now I understood the problem correctly

Comment: Chris, I think you are right, but how can we access that selector to properly hide it? Perhaps maybe append a class which is hidden instead of hide() ?

Comment: I don't think that it is a clone of actual element, that won't be right way to create a dialog, otherwise styles and events assigned to selectors won't work

Comment: but it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/h3kBE/

Comment: i cannot reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/6ctw9/2/

Comment: I guess you have some "conflict" between your JS functions, maybe there is a logic error, some function that shows the div before dialog is being opened and so on

Answer (score 0):

myDialog and everything inside it, including myDiv, should automatically be hidden when the dialog is closed. You don't need to write any additional code to make that happen. If isn't working, then something else is wrong. My guess based on the code sample in your question:

1. Hide myDialog by default, e.g., `<div id="MyDialog" style="display:none;">...`
2. Explicitly open the dialog when appropriate, e.g., `$("#myDialog").dialog("open");`

Answer (score 0):

you probably just need to reference those elements relative to the dialog.

```
  $("#myDialog").dialog().find('#myDiv').hide()
```

-edit-

```
    close: function(event, ui){
     $(this).find('#myDiv').hide()
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need to use `find` method because he already uses an ID selector and it is unique. and existing code works well unless he has another logic errors in code

Comment: That's not correct.  When he is putting html inside of the dialog, jquery is cloning that html.  which means there is now two copies of that element with that id.  Then jquery will only return the first one it finds if you select by id.

Comment: jQuery doesn't clone the content, that would be "not smart" way to create a dialog as I already mentioned in my previous comment because of events, styles and etc

Comment: and to be sure look at the inspector ;)
P.S. having 2 elements in the page that have the same id is a can be considered as a "syntax error"